# Control references in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function eegetdropdownvalue_str(ctl){return ctl.selectedIndex>=0&&ctl[ctl.selectedIndex]?ctl[ctl.selectedIndex].value:''}
```

The above function is called with

```
co.p1A10=eegetdropdownvalue_str(document.formc.p1A10);
```

I want to switch the call over to jQuery to drop the document.form reference however doing this

```
co.p1A10=eegetdropdownvalue_str($('p1A10'));
```

Does not reference the control correctly - How should I do this?

Comment: What's `formc` (maybe "forms"?)? And what is `p1A10` — the id of the form?

Comment: formc is the id of the form and p1A10 is a combobox in this case - trying to take it out of the form and into a CMS  where it doesnt end up in a form and

Answer (score 2):

There's two things wrong with your code.

**First**, `$('p1A10')` references nothing.

jQuery selectors work almost identically (if not completely identically) to the way css works.

So, just ask yourself how you would reference the object(s) in question in CSS and you're half way there.

I'm assuming that p1A10 is the `name` or `id` of an object. Since we're using CSS/jQuery syntax, this should be an id, although you can select by other attributes such as `$("select[name='p1A10']")` .

To reference an object by ID we use the `#` character (again, just like in CSS). So we can  select your node via `$('#p1A10')`.

The **second** problem is that your function is expecting a DOM object not a jQuery object. To keep your code intact, we need to say `$('#p1A10')[0]` where 0 is the first element within the collection of jQuery elements.

I've provided two examples to explain this a little better. One uses your existing infrastructure and one replaces it.

http://jsfiddle.net/TD6Uu/5/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Given a form with id `formc` and a select with name `p1A10` you could e.g. use:

```
o.p1A10 = eegetdropdownvalue_str($('#formc select[name="p1A10"]').get(0));
```

If this doesn't do it, please provide use with the exact HTML structure